# The first item in listview does not gets the focus

Tags: android, listview, focus

I have an edittext and a listview in a linear layout.Suppose there are 5 results currently visible in the list out of total 10.When i scroll down from the edit text on to the listview, the 5th item in the listview(I suppose its always the last one) gets the focus,  instead of the first item! How should i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a Handler, as a field in your Activity. Like this:

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

2) When you create the ListView, add a OnFocusChangeListener, like shown below.

```
    myList.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                myHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        myList.setSelection(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Although this works but This is a costly call i suppose. here is what the documentation also says "This method is only for use in very special circumstances -- it can easily starve the message queue, cause ordering problems, or have other unexpected side-effects.".I wonder why i need a handler for that?

Comment: If you share your Handler with other routines, which are not to solve the problem focusing the ListView, you really have to worry about using this method. Therefore, I suggest you use the Handler created just for this purpose. Doing like that you will not have queue problems.

Comment: This solution is far from elegant. In the case you are facing, the focus behavior of the ListView should be this by default or there must be an specific property for that purpose. For now, that's my suggestion in this case.