# focus going on fourth item after listview is getting filled

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using listview in RelativeLayout. After filling listview with Efficient Adapter, the focus movement is directly going to fourth element of listview. I want to go the selection to first item of listview when listview filled with item or refreshed.
Below is the code:

```
  mAdapter_New.notifyDataSetChanged();
lt1.addFooterView(footerView);
 lt1.setAdapter(mAdapter_New);
lt1.setSelection(0); 
       lt1.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

The layout file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/White">
<RelativeLayout .... >
    <LinearLayout ...>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/listtv01" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="false" 
android:layout_below="@+id/ril_prg" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
android:divider="@color/Grey" 
android:dividerHeight="1dip" 
android:headerDividersEnabled="false" 
android:footerDividersEnabled="false" 
android:clickable="true" 
android:background="@color/White" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The first item in listview does not gets the focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825398/the-first-item-in-listview-does-not-gets-the-focus)